# JSoup, remove Elements

Tags: java, jsoup, element

Basically what I want to achieve is to remove the elements that have a `colspan=2` and only leave the other Elements. I am actually trying it with this code but it's not working, any Ideas ? :)

So this is my Code:

```
try {
      docSpielTagSpiele = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
} catch (IOException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(FullFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

Elements spieltagElements = docSpielTagSpiele.select("div#Content > div.rahmen > div.rahmenbody > table.Spiele > tbody > tr > td.Heim");
System.out.println(spieltagElements);
System.out.println("SIZE: " + spieltagElements.size());

System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------");

Elements el = spieltagElements.select("td.Heim[colspan=2]").remove();

System.out.println(el);
System.out.println("SIZE: " + el.size());

System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------");

System.out.println("ELEMENTS THAT NEED TO BE REMOVED");
Elements remove = spieltagElements.select("td.Heim[colspan=2]");
System.out.println(remove);
System.out.println("SIZE: " + remove.size());
```

and this is my output:

http://pastebin.com/ajY88FGn (can't show it directly, though the editor is parsing it directly...)

Thanks already :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method works as it should. The elements are removed from the DOM, [as explained in the documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html#remove--). The remove method does not empty the collection of elements that you prepared before. So `spieltagElements` will remain as it was. The document `docSpielTagSpiele` however does not contain the removed elements any more. To see that, you need to query the original `docSpielTagSpiele` again.

Comment: no problem. I guess it is not that clear from it. But how would Jsoup know which references to the elements you still keep in the code? Removing them only from the DOM makes actually sense when you think about it that way. If my answer helped, you may upvote it. If it solves your issue please consider accepting the answer.